# I'm looking for a power or spell which places a secondary rider effect upon a target, which can then be triggered later?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I'm looking for a power or spell (as opposed to an ability) which places a secondary rider effect upon an unwilling target, which can then be triggered at will at a later time?

For example, the Monk's quivering palm strike almost fits this category, except that it is an ability, not a power or spell.

The best answer will have the power or spell with the most difficulty for the unwilling target to save/prevent/counter the effects as the primary determinant, and the longest duration before the window of opportunity to trigger the secondary effects expires as the secondary determinant.

The character in question is looking for means of playing pranks on others without getting caught.

Comment: I've updated my answer somewhat. Hope this helps 8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "powers" are okay, there's a great way to prank entire groups of characters.

**IMPLANTED SUGGESTION**

The psionic power **Implanted Suggestion** from *Complete Psionic* acts the same way as the Suggestion spell, except for several major details. It's a 4th level power (higher DC), it has 1 standard action manifesting time (and as with all other psionics, you don't have to speak, making it VERY stealthy), it can affect multiple targets at once via augmentation (so at high enough level, you may put a Suggestion at your entire party), and best of all - it has a trigger event specified by you, and a duration of 1 day/level for it to trigger.

Just from the top of my head - let's say the DMPC opposing party is about to have an audience with the king. You put a suggestion on them to proclaim in unison "What an ugly wench!", and for the trigger you specify the moment the king mentions his beloved daughter... Yeah, not everyone is going to like this joke, but you are 8)

**Rider effect**: easy, just make the trigger a password spoken by yourself.

**BESTOW CURSE**

Then again, you can't ignore the classics, and few spells are just as classic for pranking as a Bestow Curse. Which is actually Permanent (on top of that you can only dispel it with Remove Curse, Break Enchantment, Wish or Miracle, so you all the Dispel Magic in the world can't put a halt on your pranks)

No, we're not talking about those nasty and openly aggressive penalties to rolls, or chances to skip a turn - what we're interested in is the last part of the spell's description: *" You may also invent your own curse, but it should be no stronger than those described above"*. Those described effects? Really powerful stuff even with the basic Bestow Curse spell (not to mention its upgrade Greater Bestow Curse), so your homebrewed curses are mostly limited by the vast and twisted power of your sick imagination.

Have a metal basin hit the party fighter on the head for 1 nonlethal HP every time he draws a sword! Make it so the party cleric hears someone blowing raspberries during his daily prayers even when he's alone on an uninhabited island in the middle of a closed demiplane! Give the wizard's familiar a bombastic flatuence that starts to act every 1d10 minutes and makes everyone in his square (including himself) roll a Fort DC 10 or become sickened (or nauseated if already sickened! And remember, natural 1 on a save is an auto-fail!). Make the party bard turn green and bulky whenever he gets mad (without the stat boosts) so that it gets so much more difficult for him to maneuver in risky social interactions! Give the king a glorious and mighty headache that only becomes manageable whenever he sees a fat, ugly and smelly orc (preferably, his general that was a pain in your behind since the get-go) perform a belly dance routine while wearing a frilly and semi-transparent little pink swimsuit! This stuff basically writes itself! So go ahead, start cursing and don't ever, ever stop!

Just, you know... Maybe cast it as an Ocular, Invisible spell (2 feats, +2 spell levels), so that you don't have to touch your prank victims - sure, you can cast it normally on a party member, but I don't think it's going to be as easy with, say, a king. It would be so much harder to backtrack it to you this way.

**Rider effect**: That's a bit trickier, but bear with me for a little.
The "homebrewed curse" part of the spell has several mitigating factors that we have to take into the consideration:
-It has to be of a same or a smaller scale than the other options given (that is, -6 to an ability score/-4 to attacks, saves, skill checks and ability checks/50% chance of inaction)
-It must not infringe on the territory of the spell Mark of Justice
-It must not infringe on the territory of the spell Geas/Quest

So, let's see what we CAN'T do with this spell:
-We can't make sonething more serious than the other options given (duh).
-We can't make the cursed act upon a prolonged compulsion.  The only effect that FORCES the subject to do something has a duration of 1 turn (but can repeat for several turns in a row).
-We can't give the subject a trigger for -6 to ability score/-4 to his rolls/50% chance of inactivity, or an effect with the same severity.
-In fact, we can't create any trigger that doesn't have anything to do with the curse in question.

So, what CAN we do? Let's see several examples:
-Can we make the subject say "Polo" once in a minute? Sure, it doesn't give such severe penalties to stealth and social interactions, and while it can impede upon his spellcasting, it's far less drastic than 50% chance of inactivity (plus, he can PLAN for the next Polo Outburst).
-Can we make the subject say "Polo" whenever he hears anyone says "Marco"? Sure. It's basically a tweak of the previous curse, with the curse not being constantly active, but letting the other characters abuse the results of such curse. If I were a DM, I'd say that a cursed spellcaster that's forced to say "Polo" in rapid succession has some Arcane Failure Chance (like, 10-15%, we don't want to oversell it), plus limit the amount of times he has to say "Polo" during a round in a combat situation.
-Can we make the subject say "Polo" whenever he hears anyone say "Raxacoricofallapatorius"? Sure, it's just another word. A hard one, as that, but if anyone can say it within the earshot of the subject, the subject will say "Polo".
-Can we make the character say "Polo" whenever something ELSE happens? Like, if he hears a raven's cry, or sees a flying arrow, or when someone misses him in battle? Sure, it's just a tweak of the previous options, we just have to specify a different trigger, and the character will keep saying "Polo" to it.
-Can we make something else happen to character whenever the curse is triggered? Well, it's not a "Bestow Polo Outburst" spell, as long as the results are smaller than the fitst three options described by the spell, the curse is limited by whatever you design it to do.

Basically - what you need to do to make a simple Bestow Curse act as a pre-cast spell with an at-will rider effect, is word the conditions of the curse in such a way, that it acts on a very specific and difficult to encounter on occasion algorithm before YOU decide it's time to activate it. It can be "when the planets align themselves above your head, you'll stub your toe!", or "whenever anyone ever asks what reward for your services you desire, you'll blurt "your shoes"!", or "whenever you hear the word "beetlejuice", you'll lose your pants!". Just be wary that all of this must be agreed upon, at the very very least, with the DM - or you may find out that planets never align, the questgivers always give pre-determined rewards and your hapless victim can't hear the trigger words since it's deafened. And all of that in the *best* case scenario (for your character, that is).

**PRESTIDIGITATION**

And then, there's this little cantrip. This spell does it all - cleans, flavores, soils, colors, moves etc - no wonder many players call it "0th level Wish". Pranking with this spell requires either a little bit more planning or a bit more intimacy than a Bestow Curse or Implanted Suggestion (it has a range of 10 feet around you), but it's readily available to you from your very first adventurer level.

You can get some rotten fish (not the Nordic kind either) from the fishmonger's dumpster, mesh it, color it, flavor it and sell as a hout cousine for platinum coins per pound as long as you do it quick enough! Or create a magical army of technicolored warponies to make the army of oversensitive but manly orcs lose their spirits - or do whatever else you can think of as long as it's within one hour from the moment of casting...

Or you can craft (or buy) a Permanent item of Prestidigitation for 2000*1*1*0.5=1000 gp and have it active permanently! Your trash-to-hotdogs schemes won't be discovered for months! You'll be able to color the entire orc cities in girlish acid pink! You'll be able to soil the pants of whoever crosses you at your leisure! You'll always be clean and smell nicely!

Basically, even for non-prankers - best low-level magical item ever. For prankers? A must-have.

**Rider effect**: Easy. The rider effect is this spell running out, showing everyone involved horrible (and sometimes even gross) truth. For permanent item, ask DM for an off switch, or if a targeted dispel on the item erases all its effects. If no - just cast a Dispel Magic on a target/area as a trigger, that WILL work as per rules.

**IMPORTANT POST SCRIPTUM**

Obviously, work with your DM. He should assign the mechanical values to things like the strength of Wizard's Familiar's flatuence, or the severity of damage caused by the application of a metal basin to the fighter's cranium, or the availability and price of a permanent Prestidigitation item. If you're the DM, go nuts, but not TOO nuts, or your players may not have too much fun with stuff like this (especially if it's not a comedic game)

Comment: Psionic suggestion is a great suggestion but the other two aren't appropriate-- they have to do things *right away* and can't be 'dormant' until triggered later like the question is asking for.

Comment: Oh, right. Added the commentary on the rider effect at the end of each paragraph

Comment: Your 'Bestow Curse' rider effect says 'definitely' for things that are at best 'with significant GM generosity'.

Comment: Not really. If we can make a person say "Polo" when we say "Marco" (absolutely within the rules of the Bestow Curse), we can make a "Chupoclops" (another, just rarer word) cause a basin to fall on the cursed person's head (another insignificant by its power curse). It's definitely not even AS powerful as the other effects described in the spell.

Comment: And see, here's the real beauty here - you don't need to make it a "he hears me saying the word", it can be " Whenever he HEARS the word". During a co-op infiltration mission to a high court ball, take an alias Lord Moldybutt. The word "Moldybutt" is your curse password, whenever your cursed bodyguard hears it, he slaps himself. The word is nigh impossible to guess beforehand, and is going to be passed just like that during the ball (and afterwards too). Excellent prank which could be put in action AGES before the mission.

Comment: Rewrote the part about the rider effect of Bestow Curse, now it makes more sense 8)

Comment: See, this depends on how you evaluate power.  In the old-school groups I've played with any kind of conditional functionality (if X than Y, P whenever Q) is considered to be difficult, powerful, and rare.  Consider that *contingency*, which *only* does what you are suggesting (lets one thing happen when another thing you specify happens) is a 6th level spell. Adding a 6th level spell effect is kind of a big deal, and none of the listed examples seem to imply that any kind of conditional functionality is actually possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57653/discussion-between-the-dark-wanderer-and-baka-mastermind).

Answer (score 2):

## Mark of Justice

The [*Mark of Justice*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/markOfJustice.htm) spell has Saving Throw: None (but allows Spell Resistance), and has a permanent duration.  It also has:

> Like the effect of bestow curse, a mark of justice cannot be dispelled, but it can be removed with a break enchantment, limited wish, miracle, remove curse, or wish spell. Remove curse works only if its caster level is equal to or higher than your mark of justice caster level. These restrictions apply regardless of whether the mark has activated

This spell beats *[Quest](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/geasQuest.htm)* in that the duration can't just be waited out, the 'prank' part can be nearly anything (*Bestow Curse* is extremely open ended), particularly it can certainly be limited to merely a prank rather than *Quest*'s potentially life-threatening severity.  *Quest* is, however, more difficult to remove and easier to place: It doesn't allow *Break Enchantment* and it has a range of Close rather than Touch.

*Mark of Justice* does have a **10 minute** casting time, which means it's not the sort of thing one can, say, do with a sleight of hand check.  If you are planning on pranking your party members it works fine because you can almost definitely have a 10-minute window with them asleep where you can do this sort of thing unobserved, but for pranking people once they wise up it may be a bit less useful (in which case *Silent Still Geas*, which merely requires you be within ~100 ft of the target with line of effect for 10 minutes, is superior)

Comment: The casting time of **ten minutes**, plus the requirement of writing directly on the person, makes this one a bit tough to pull off. I suppose that sneaking up on someone during their normal sleep period, perhaps combined with some other effect to keep them asleep or unconscious during said writing might work....

Comment: @nijineko Sounds like an excellent argument in favor of a house rule allowing creatures to deal nonlethal damage when making coup de grace attempts.

Comment: @HeyICanChan It certainly would make for some fun wake-up calls!

Comment: @nijineko Oh, yes, sorry, I assumed you were desiring to prank your fellow party members so access to their sleeping bodies for 10 minutes wouldn't be particularly onerous.  I realize you didn't actually say that now, will update to warn about problems.